# How to Reverse OFFSET without ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I got something like this query (actually mine is more complex, but you can see what's happening with the one below)

`SELECT posts.id, posts.text, posts.date
FROM posts
WHERE posts.text LIKE '%keyword%'
ORDER BY posts.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20";`

But I got a lot of posts (> 40k) and this ORDER BY is making everything really slow, reversing tons of data. If I remove the `ORDER BY` it goes much faster.

Is there any way to get latest 20 posts without bring me all data from search, reverse it, then get the 20 first rows from result ordered?

Comment: I don't think so, because the condition on `posts.text` causes a problem with indexes.  You might try something like `where posts.date >= date_sub(now(), interval 30 day)` and create an index on `posts.date`.

Comment: But it will limit my results to 30 days. I made something like this when we need to get most recent posts: I get only `AND DATE(posts.date) > subdate(current_date, 1)` . Instead `ORDER BY post.date DESC` all posts, I reverse significantly less results. I can't limit the result by date in this case described here.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you are storing lists of keywords in the column `posts.text`.  You might have better luck with a separate junction table (if these are comma-separated lists) or using a full text index (if this is just text that you are searching).

Answer (score 0):

You can try order by id desc

Is your `date` field a date type?